# Python 2.7, docx, replace text with special characters

Tags: python-2.7, special-characters, python-docx

I am trying to figure out how to replace text with special characters.
This is what i have right now. It works fine for replacing normal text, but it can't handle special characters like Č,Ř,Ž,Ý...

```
def printInfo( q, qy ):
        for p in document.paragraphs:
                if qy in p.text:
                    inline = p.runs
                    for i in range(len(inline)):
                        if qy in inline[i].text:
                            text = inline[i].text.replace(qy, q)
                            inline[i].text = text
                    print p.text   
        return;
printInfo('text with special character', 'old text')
```

Error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Dopisy\example3.py", line 83, in <module>
    printInfo( x, 'prijmeni')
  File "C:\Dopisy\example3.py", line 68, in printInfo
    inline[i].text = text
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\python_docx-0.8.6-py2.7.egg\docx\text\run.py", line 163, in text
    self._r.text = text
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\python_docx-0.8.6-py2.7.egg\docx\oxml\text\run.py", line 104, in text
    _RunContentAppender.append_to_run_from_text(self, text)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\python_docx-0.8.6-py2.7.egg\docx\oxml\text\run.py", line 134, in append_to_run_from_text
    appender.add_text(text)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\python_docx-0.8.6-py2.7.egg\docx\oxml\text\run.py", line 143, in add_text
    self.flush()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\python_docx-0.8.6-py2.7.egg\docx\oxml\text\run.py", line 165, in flush
    self._r.add_t(text)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\python_docx-0.8.6-py2.7.egg\docx\oxml\text\run.py", line 41, in add_t
    t = self._add_t(text=text)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\python_docx-0.8.6-py2.7.egg\docx\oxml\xmlchemy.py", line 275, in _add_child
    setattr(child, key, value)
  File "lxml.etree.pyx", line 953, in lxml.etree._Element.text.__set__ (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:44956)
  File "apihelpers.pxi", line 677, in lxml.etree._setNodeText (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:20273)
  File "apihelpers.pxi", line 1395, in lxml.etree._utf8 (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:26485)
ValueError: All strings must be XML compatible: Unicode or ASCII, no NULL bytes or control characters
```

From what i have found so far it is probably the same problem as described here: [0
How to resolve "ValueError: All strings must be XML compatible...](https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/question/how-to-resolve-valueerror-all-strings-must-be-xml-compatible-unicode-or-ascii-no-null-bytes-or-control-characters-error-56975)
But the described solution didn't work for me, or I just don't know how to use it in my case.
If you could help me in any way it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If the value you assign to Run.text is not of type unicode, it's not going to like non-ASCII characters. What do you get when you insert the line: `print isinstance(text, unicode)` just before the `inline[i].text = text` line? If that's False you need to fix that up first.

Comment: Thanks. I used q = unicode(q, 'latin1') and it removed the error message. But now instead character 'ř' it replaces the text with 'ø'. I have tried a bunch of things to fix it a nothing helps so far.

Comment: This could help with selecting proper encoding instead of `latin1`: in Python3 (I can't use Python 2.7 right now), `print ( 'ěščřžýĚŠČŘŽÝ', 'ěščřžýĚŠČŘŽÝ'.encode('cp1250').decode('cp1252'))` returns `ěščřžýĚŠČŘŽÝ ìšèøžýÌŠÈØŽÝ`.

Comment: You are amazing. In my case q = q.decode('cp1250') fixed the problem.
Thanks.